# Carregamento de páginas igual G+

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Estou me arriscando no PHP e fazendo um painel administrativo simples, sem framework, para gerenciar usuários inscritos, como posso fazer o carregamento de páginas no admin sem recarregar os menu lateral e a barra de navbar, igual o G+?

Obs.: Não precisa ter o efeito, somente o carregamento do conteúdo.

Comment: não quero usar frameworks, quero tentar fazer com liguagens puras. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Verdade, não havia entendido completamente isso no enunciado. Mesmo não querendo utilizar frameworks, você usará jQuery? Você pode fazer algo semelhante com AJAX: ao invés de você redirecionar para outra página, você obtém o conteúdo desta com JavaScript e exibe em algum elemento da página atual.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, pelo menos jQuery vou utilizar e acabei de fazer.
`// Loader das páginas internas
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('a.ajaxMenu').click(function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.conteudo').load($(this).attr('href'));
        });
    });`

Obrigado!